# Export Django model/classes to SQL statement

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I've created a web application using Django. I'm not very happy with it, and would like to export/translate the *whole* Django model I've created as an SQL statement.

I know the following statement prints the an SQL statement for incremental changes to the database:

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate polls 0001
```

But how to I export the initial (whole) model into an sql file?

Theoretically, I could simply export an SQL dump directly from the database. But my database has become messy (additional tables) and my `models.py` is a clean formulation of the original database.

Comment: As far as I know, the `python manage.py sql` command that did what you want is deprecated since Django 1.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Rename your `migrations` folder to `foo` so Django can't find it (or delete it altogether, if you're brave)
2. Delete or rename the `django_migrations` table
3. `python manage.py migrate --fake`
4. `python manage.py makemigrations polls`
5. `python manage.py sqlmigrate polls 0001`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. After the first command, it says `No migrations to apply. Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied. Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.` After the second: `CommandError: App 'mainapp' does not have migrations`

Comment: @Ratnanil I think I had missed a step. You might need to rename your `django_migrations` table

Comment: faking a migration now works, but the error `ComandError: App...` still appears. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Ratnanil I guess if you've moved the migrations folder and renamed the column in the database, you can just create a new initial migration as usual with `makemigrations` and then use `sqlmigrate` to see the SQL statement. let me know if that works and I'll edit the answer. unfortunately, I'm doing this from memory as I'm not on a django-powered machine atm

Comment: yes it did! After step 3 insert `python manage.py makemigrations mainapp` and then `python manage.py sqlmigrate mainapp 0001`. Update your answer and I will gladly accept. Thank you!